# Windows explorer jumping to the foreground

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I am on Windows 11 22H2 (22621.898). When I have a file explorer window open in the background and am using another application, file explorer windows keeps randomly and suddenly jumping to the foreground. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I do not have a fix, though I suffer from the same problem on Win 11 Pro 22H2 (22621.1105). There's a thread on MS' site that has complaints about it with some more details as well.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-most-recently-opened-explorer-window/26e097bd-1eba-4462-99bd-61597b5195a0

Article on it. Seems to be a Windows 11 bug: https://www.windowslatest.com/2023/01/04/windows-11-22h2-bug-file-explorer-opens-randomly-when-using-another-app/

For me, I'm also using an nVidia GPU, and an NVMe drive as my OS drive.

Comment: Same issue, if I'm browsing in Chrome with Explorer open but not focused, it'll randomly pop-up and cover Chrome. Really really annoying. Unsure if this helps, but I also have a Network Drive mapped with Offline Files enabled on Windows 11.

Answer (score 5):

A possible fix for this is included in [build 23403.1001](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2023/03/08/announcing-windows-11-insider-preview-build-23403/), which was released to the Dev Channel on 8 March 2023:

> [File Explorer]
>
> - Fixed an underlying issue believed to be the cause of File Explorer unexpectedly jumping into the foreground sometimes.

Comment: Just FYI. This has not fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I've seen this issue reappear in recent builds aswell, though not as often, but had the feeling it was definitely gone inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

As the build 23403.1001 "fix" [apparently](https://superuser.com/questions/1755139/windows-explorer-jumping-to-the-foreground/1819877?noredirect=1#comment2863183_1775369) didn't fix this, our hopes are now on [KB5032288](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/december-4-2023-kb5032288-os-builds-22621-2792-and-22631-2792-preview-538fbe4a-e9de-4312-85cd-d870444341d0), released Dec 4th:

> This update addresses an issue that affects File Explorer windows. When you do not expect them, they appear in the foreground.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).